# What is a non-concave and non-convex polygon called?

Tags: terminology, polygons

I am writing a software function to plot the outer points of an n-sided polygon and I'm having trouble ensuring I use the correct terminology. The function I've written simply renders the calculated points of a predetermined polygon in two dimensional space. These polygons are neither convex nor concave and thus I believe the name I should give the function is ***Render Uniform Polygon***; however, I believe **uniform** may not be the correct word and could end up in a debate over the name. The function itself performs three actions to achieve the goal:

1. Calculate the angle of each point $\theta_n$.
2. Calculate the new position $P_n$.
3. Render a 3px by 3px dot at the new position.

The math for calculating $\theta_n$ is:

$$\theta_n = \frac{\biggl(\bigl(\frac{360°}{p}\bigr)n + \phi\biggr)\pi}{180°}$$

Where:

- $p$ is the number of points in the polygon.
- $n$ is the current point.
- $\phi$ is the global rotation angle.

Once $\theta_n$ has been calculated with the math above, I then use it to calculate the new position with the following:

$$P_{_n{x, y}} = C_{x, y} + (\cos(\theta_n), \sin(\theta_n))r$$

Where:

- $P_n$ is current point's position.
- $C_{x, y}$ is the center of the polygon.
- $r$ is the radius of the polygon.

This method can be used to render any polygon with three sides or more, and since the radius is predefined there isn't a case where the polygon can be convex or concave.

---

What is a polygon that is neither convex nor concave called?

Comment: All regular polygons are convex. As far as I know, a polygon that is neither convex nor concave is called "neither convex nor concave". I don't know of any special term for that.

Comment: @AdrianKeister So simply ***Render Polygon*** should suffice in this case without causing any confusion?

Comment: Sure! A regular polygon is a polygon, but not the reverse. So if you happen to be constructing regular polygons, a `construct_polygon()` method is a fine name for that.

Comment: For me, a concave polygon is one that has at least one angle greater than $\pi$ and a convex one has no angles greater than $\pi$.  In that case there are no polygons that are neither concave nor convex.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Excellent point, I agree!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see your polygon is convex. It's a regular polygon whose vertices are equidistant on the circle with radius $r$ and center $C$.